# do/while loop not working in Java with functions

Tags: java

In this code, the user types in yes if they would like to play again
I have to use functions for this code, I cannot simply state `while(again.equals("yes"));`.

Part of code:

```
do{ 
    System.out.print("Play Again? Yes/No: ");
    String again=keyboard.nextLine(); 
    boolean running=playAgain(again); 
} while(running == true);
```

My question is why is `}while(running==true);` a syntax error? I declared the variable above it, shouldn't that allow it to run?

Comment: Sorry about that! My question is why is }while(running==true); a syntax error? I declared the variable, shouldn't that allow the do/while loop to run?

Comment: because you miss a `do {`? Also note that `running` is undefined outside the do/while loop

Comment: Because variables declared inside the loop body are not in-scope in the condition in a do/while loop.

Comment: I forgot to include the do{ when I pasted this code, my bad. The variables that call the function are in the do/while loop as well, and I want the code to return information between the functions the second time. I am unsure how I could manage that without defining running in the do/while loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a "do" statement first, i.e. `do { statements; } while (condition)`. Also

- you don't need to save the return from playAgain() into a variable, you can call it directly from the while().
- There are many Java tutorials out there, try the official Oracle ones from starters: [The while and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Update

```
String again; // <== declared here because conditions inside
              //     while cannot see variables defined inside the do {} block
do {
    System.out.print("Play Again? Yes/No: ");
    again = keyboard.nextLine();
} while (playAgain(again));
```

Comment: Yes sorry, updated answer.

Comment: great name, great answer. :)